# Jquery slideDown and slideUp

Tags: jquery

Why doesn't this work??

```
    $("#panellink").click(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass("hover"),
    $("#playerpanel").slideDown(250);
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass("hover"),
    $("#playerpanel").slideUp(250);
    }
);
```

All I want is when they click on the link the #playerpanel slides down and when clicked again it slides up???

It slides down when I click the link like expected, and when I click the link again it doesn't slide up and just stays there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$("#panellink").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass( "hover" );
    $(this).slideToggle( 250 );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `toggle` instead of `click`.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

> The .toggle() method binds a handler for the click event, so the rules
>   outlined for the triggering of click apply here as well.

```
$("#panellink").toggle(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $("#playerpanel").slideDown(250);
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        $("#playerpanel").slideUp(250);
    }
);
```

Plus, you had commas after the add/remove class calls...should be semicolons.

I think this will help with the alternating functions that you want to do.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your HTML code is correct, and that you have defined the elements you are using in JQuery (i.e. an element with id="panellink", and one with id="panelplayer").

I'm looking at the .click() event of the JQuery API (http://api.jquery.com/click/), and it doesn't seem to accept a pair of functions as handler.

What you could do is do some checking, and then act on the result.
You could check if the element has the `hover` class or not, and then treat each case.

```
$("#panellink").click( function() {
    if( $(this).hasClass("hover") ) {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        $("#playerpanel").slideUp(250);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $("#playerpanel").slideDown(250);
    }
)
```

Note: Also, I just noticed what I presume are typos. Both addClass and removeClass statements should be terminated by a semicolon `;`, not a comma `,`.

Hope this helps